# SignatureDoesNotMatch in Amazon s3 Rest API

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, amazon-web-services, progress-bar

I've been trying to get this to work for 1 week but always I am getting the same error. I also tried to debug the Signature function but I dnt where is the exact problem..I want to upload the file with progress bar as well as want to add the resume and pause functionality in REST-PHP.
**I am following the below link a :-** http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/uploading_files_to_amazon_s3_with_rest_api.xml
 Please provide me any proper solution.

**I am getting this response:-**

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden x-amz-request-id: 3B621260770DE679 x-amz-id-2: vuB+qHCRxq6CdRKIoso82GXO1O0gQNDEs5rLi3my/YiD535nyZQ6Ls64jZ5hB2KW Content-Type: application/xml Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 09:01:52 GMT Connection: close Server: AmazonS3 3ef **SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.AKIAJA6EQQ475TUGTSEQPUT image/jpeg** Thu, 11 Dec 2014 09:01:52 +0000 x-amz-acl:public-read /s3.regionname.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/Desss.jpgsdpF9q1WTYzHuLuytn7Dv+3xdIY=50 55 54 0a 0a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70 65 67 0a 54 68 75 2c 20 31 31 20 44 65 63 20 32 30 31 34 20 30 39 3a 30 31 3a 35 32 20 2b 30 30 30 30 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 2f 73 33 2e 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 32 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 6e 61 6e 6f 68 65 61 6c 2d 69 62 6d 2f 44 65 73 73 73 2e 6a 70 673B621260770DE679vuB+qHCRxq6CdRKIoso82GXO1O0gQNDEs5rLi3my/YiD535nyZQ6Ls64jZ5hB2KW 0

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that sort of error message when I'm using an invalid secret key and access key OR my permissions for my user aren't set up for the service I am trying to access.

- Can you definitely access the bucket using another S3 client (e.g. CloudBerry or S3 addon for firefox) using the same keys?
- I would try and use a more recent tutorial, the one you linked looks like it's not using the latest version of the AWS SDK which is awesome - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html

A benefit of using the latest version of the SDK is that you will write less low level code and the error messages will probably be more helpful in identifying your issue.

Comment: I am using the correct secret and access key..as well as I have the permission for my user to access the s3 bucket, because I am able to upload the file using php and java with same credential..But for resume and pause I need the REST API in php..so i am running the rest api code and still i am getting the signaturedoes not match error..